# Adding an signed integer beyond 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun3(int a, int b, int c)
{
   printf("%d \n", a+b+c );
}
void fun2 ( int x, int y)
{
   fun3(0x33333333,0x30303030, 0x31313131);
   printf("%d \n", x+y);
}
fun1 (int x)
{
   fun2(0x22222222,0x20202020);
   printf("%d  \n", x);
}
main()
{
  fun1(0x1111111);
}
```

I'm going through the above program for stack corruption. I am getting the o/p for the above program with some undesired values. All I could understand is if the added value is beyond 0xFFFFFFFF then the small negative integer becomes the largest value say -1 becomes 0xFFFFFFFF. Any insights on this

Comment: Share the unexpected values you're seeing, as well as the values you expect?

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, but chances are you're seeing signed integer overflow of [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) numbers.

Comment: Not sure how stack corruption plays into this. There does not appear to be any stack corruption in this program. Also, it's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

To @Cornstalks' point: `INT_MIN` is `0x80000000`, and `(int)-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF` in 2's complement (on a 32-bit system, anyway).

This allows the instruction set to do things in signed arithmetic like:

```
1 + -2 = -1
```

becomes (as signed `short`s, for brevity)

```
0x0001 + 0xFFFE = 0xFFFF
```

... then:

```
1 + -1 = 0
```

is represented internally with overflow as

```
0x0001 + 0xFFFF = 0x0000
```

Also to @Cornstalks' point: the internal representation (as well as overflow addition) is an implementation detail. C implementations (and instruction sets) need not represent integers in 2's complement, so providing hex values for signed integer types may tie you to a subset of C implementations.

Comment: To @pablo1977's point: if you re-typed all your `int`s as `unsigned int`s and used `%u` instead of `%d` in your `printf`s, you might get what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT (Corrections)** (I missed the point. My answer is right for constants, but the question contains parameters of functions, then what happens here is overflow of signed integer objects and, as correctly pointed out @Cornstalks in his comment, this is undefined behaviour). 
**/EDIT**

In `fun1()` you are using `printf()` in a wrong way.
You wrote `"%d"` to accept an `int`, but this is not true if your number is greater that `MAX_INT`.

You have to check the value of `MAX_INT` in your system.
If you write an integer constant **in hexadecimal format**, the standard C (ISO C99 or C11) tries to put the value in the first type that the constant can fit, by following this order:

> int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int,
>   unsigned long long int.

Thus, if you have a constant greater that `MAX_INT` (the max. value in the range of `int`), your constant (if positive) has type `unsigned int`, but the directive `%d` expected a `signed int` value. Thus, it will be shown some negative number.

Worst, if your constant is a value greater than `UMAX_INT` (the max. value in the range of `unsigned int`) then the type of the constant will be the first of `long int, unsigned long int, long long int`, with precision strictly bigger than of `unsigned int`.
This implies that `%d` becomes a wrong directive.

If you cannot be completely sure about how big will be your values, you could do a cast to the biggest integer type:

```
  printf("%lld", (long long int) 0x33333333333);
```

The directive `%lld` stands for `long long int`.
If you are interested always in positive values, you have to use `%llu` and cast to `unsigned long long int`:

```
  printf("%llu", (unsigned long long int) 0x33333333333);
```

In this way, you avoids any "funny" numbers, as much as, you show big numbers without loosing any precision.

**Remark:** The constants `INT_MAX`, `UINT_MAX`, and the like, are in [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

**Important:** The automatic sequence of casts is only valid for octal and hexadecimal constants. For decimal constants there is another rule:

> int, long int, long long int.

Comment: I have corrected my answer, because does not fit well in the question. The question contaings code with `int` parameters, so the comment of @Cornstalks (at the question) applies. However, I think it is interesting to understand what the compiler does with integer constants.

Answer (score 1):

`fun3` will attempt to print the value 0x94949494.  This is greater than the max 4-byte integer value of 0x7FFFFFFF, so it will "overflow" and (on virtually every computer made today) produce (if I did my arithmetic correctly) the negative number -0x6B6B6B6C, which is -1802201964.

`fun1` and `fun2` should print the "expected" positive results.